# where is the workingset info of an eclipse workspace stored?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-neon, working-set

I have my eclipse workspace so setup so that everything required to run the eclipse IDE (eclipse neon, jdk and the workspace) are on the usb drive.

Before I created workingset in my workspace, this works all fine. I can move the usb drive to a different computer, mapping it to the same drive.

But after I created workingset on one computer, and move the usb drive to a different computer, I cannot get any of the projects displayed. The workingset I have created is available for selecting. But not matter I selected to use workingset or not, no project would show up in the project explorer.

The only solution I have right now is to recreate the workspace. But this defeat the purpose of having everything I need on the usb drive.

Comment: I think you should accept some of the answers which you got to your questions. As an act of gratitude you could also upvote the answers so the authors can get some reputation.

Answer (score 6):

The working set information is kept in the `workingsets.xml` file in the workspace metadata folder `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench`

Comment: My working sets have some duplicates that require fixing manually in `${workspace}\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.ui\dialog_settings.xml`